# Average monthly weather dataset for Europe

Tags: data-request, weather, europe

Is there a free dataset with monthly average temperature / rainfall / sunshine hours / humidity / wind figures for Europe going back 5-10yrs with geo coordinates?

Comment: do you mean "in europe" or "for all of europe"?

Comment: dataset ... for europe - whats wrong with that?